# JavaScript error on calculating average of different variables

Tags: javascript, firefox, average

I'm here because I have some trouble shooting when I calculate an average of 3 variables. Here's the script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a, b ,c;
    var moy;

    var a= prompt("Moyenne 1 ?");
    var b= prompt("Moyenne 2 ?");
    var c= prompt("Moyenne 3 ?");

    document.write(a+" "+b+" "+c)


    moy = (a+b+c)/3;
    moy= Math.floor(moy*100)/100;
    document.write("Moyenne :"+moy);
</script>
```

I noticed the error is made at "moy = (a+b+c)/3". instead of giving the correct number, it gives a much bigger number than it should give. I don't know how I could modify it, it should normally work.
I'm using Firefox build 55 (so a very recent version).

I'm new in JavaScript so I might not understand advanced script :) .
Thanks for answers, I'm completely lost with this error !

Comment: `prompt` returns a string, and `+` operator concatenates strings.

Comment: You should make sure that a, b, c are converted to numbers.  example, `var a = parseFloat(prompt("Moyenne 1?"));`

Comment: You need to parse your a, b, c strings that you get from prompt into numbers of some sort. You can use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`, but you will have to handle possible errors if users input non-numbers.

Comment: It's fixed, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Try doing

```
moy = (parseInt(a,10)+parseInt(b,10)+parseInt(c,10))/3;
```

[Refer Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 0):

Prompt return a string value when you add prompt values its concatenate all value 
and also in javscript divide concatenated values so it returns wrong answer.
so first parse all values into int.Try below code

```
var a= prompt("Moyenne 1 ?");
var b= prompt("Moyenne 2 ?");
var c= prompt("Moyenne 3 ?");
a = parseInt(a);
b = parseInt(b);
c = parseInt(c);
moy = (a+b+c)/3;
```